# Continuous Integration -Test Setup for Flash Testing Suggestion Required

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, centos, continuous-integration

I work for a Music company and have my Automation/Regression suite built on Java, jUnit, Selenium WD, Ant framework.

I use Selenium Grid to run the tests on Various Grade A browsers.

Now we are moving to Continuous Integration (Jenkins) setup and I need to run tests on a Linux machine(CentOS) which does not have a UI.

I started off with the following setups to run regression

1. Run the above mentioned tests (Java, SeleniumWD, JUnit and Ant) in Linux box using Xll, xvfb and Firefox headless browser.
2. Run the tests on the Linux box using a PhantomJS browser setup.

IN BOTH THE CASES ALL THE TEST THAT REQUIRE FLASH CONTENT TO BE LOADED AND TESTED Fails.

I am NOT ABLE TO ACCESS THE WINDOWS/MAC Machine via/through LINUX BOX (using Hub/node Selenium grid options), connection timed out error is consistent.

IT WOULD BE REALLY HELPFUL IF THERE IS SUGGESTIONS/WORK AROUND/Frameworks TO HANDLE this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Not having windows shouldn't be a problem. Can you setup XWindow sessions and run slave agent there to run real browser session?

Both Firefox and Chromium should work with CentOS.

Comment: Andy chen any inputs on how to do this? setting up XWindow sessions? pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Shyam, I haven't personally done similar testing on Linux. Based on my understanding, your problem is Selenium grid doesn't start real browser session to run test. You need to start real/visible browser session to run your tests. To verify this, you could try to setup one JNLP agent in CentOS host and run your tests.